# Close file with alias in a program

Tags: prolog

I have this code in my program:

```
open('myfile.txt',append, Stream,[alias(final)]),
some instructions
close(final).
```

If i have an error before of the `close(final)`, when i reconsult my code i have this error:

```
PERMISSION ERROR, CANNOT OPEN alias(final)
```

How can i do to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the SWI-Prolog `setup_call_cleanup/3` to ensure that your file is always closed, even when an error occurs between opening it and closing it. Something like:

```
setup_call_cleanup(
    open('myfile.txt',append, Stream,[alias(final)]),
    some_instructions
    close(final)
)
```

Consult the SWI-Prolog documentation for this predicate for more information.